# Elasticsearch using a lot of memory due to Groovy scripts

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

My ES 2.3.1 instance is using 97% of its heap, and is thus garbage collecting almost constantly, and preventing any requests from being successful. Thing is, I can't figure out what is eating up all the memory. There is no field_data usage at all.

Here are my [node stats](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e5a47a3f5476f61e2b30464bd96ccf7).

Please let me know if I can provide any more information. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is a leak suspects report screenshot based off the Elasticsearch JVM heap. It appears to be a memory leak related to groovy scripting. Is this an issue with Elasticsearch itself? Or is it possible I'm doing something wrong with the client? [image: leak suspects report]

EDIT:

Here are the scripts I'm using. This one replaces a current version of a nested object with a given id as long as the update value isn't stale:

```
def found = false;
if (ctx._source.my_field != null) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.my_field.size(); i++) {    
        if (ctx._source.my_field[i].id == 1) {      
            found = true;      
            if (ctx._source.my_field[i].timestamp < 201605011912488050) {        
                ctx._source.my_field[i] = jsonMap      } 
            else {        
                ctx.op = "none"      
            }    
        }  
    };  
    if (!found) {   
        ctx._source.my_field += jsonMap;  
    }
} else {
    ctx._source.my_field = [jsonMap];
};
```

This one simply updates a regular field if the update isn't stale:

```
if (ctx._source.my_field2 == null || ctx._source.my_field2.timestamp < 201605011913320690) {  
    ctx._source.my_field2 = jsonMap
} else {  
    ctx.op = "none"
}
```

In both the above cases, I am updating the field with a json object passed in via a map (as suggested [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16808)). I am creating and passing in the map with the following code:

```
Map<?, ?> jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(updateJson.toString(), HashMap.class);
Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of("jsonMap", jsonMap);
return new Script(script, ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, params);
```

EDIT:

A few more bits of info:

1) The number of nested documents the first script loops through is usually O(1) and no more than O(10).

2) To run the scripts, I'm first creating an updateRequest:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest()
    .index(index)
    .type(documentType)
    .id(documentId.toString())
    .script(script)
    .retryOnConflict(5)
    .upsert(getIndexRequestForDocumentUpsert(...));
```

where `getIndexRequestForDocumentUpsert(...)` just returns a simple (non-script) index request for what would be a new document. These UpdateRequests are then added to a bulk update request which contains a max of 100 updates.

3) Finally, an important thing to note is that this heap dump was taken 2 days after any updates (or queries) had been made to the index, which is why it smells of leakiness rather than just plain excessive load.

Comment: Can't tell from the stats, indeed. I suggest taking a heap dump and using yourkit or Eclipse MAT to look at its content.

Comment: @AndreiStefan added a screenshot from the memory analyzer leak suspects report. Do you think it's worth opening an issue on Github?

Comment: You are doing something heavy on the client side with some Groovy scripts.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I've added the scripts I'm using to the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: How do you run the first script and how many documents it's touching?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Added some more info regarding this to the post, let me know if you need more info

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: Not sure what to say. You'd have to dig deeper in the heap dump and see what holds a reference to those Groovy specific classes that makes them not eligible for GC.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18079) on Github and apparently this is due to a known Groovy memory leak.